# How to exit an application in window phone 8 with phonegap 2.3

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

My question is that how to exit an application in window phone 8 with phonegap 2.3.
I have used "navigatior.app.exit()",but it shows that "navigatior.app" is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that doesn't require native hacking..

If you have a Phonegap/cordova app that goes from page1.html to page2.html then follows a link back to page1.html the standard backbutton behavior wont exit the app.

Page1 >> Page 2 >> Page 1 — Windows Phone will take you to page 2 instead of exiting the app. It’s expected behavior but it’s kinda poorly documented..

Anyway I searched around for ages but didn’t find a fix that worked for me..

[Diff friendly folks see the commit that includes this fix](https://github.com/mclear/NFC_Ring_Control/commit/192f1b6224190fdd6364322981c33ec7df2049bd)

TLDR of how I fixed this is to use a JS value to track which page I’m on, if I'm on the index page I reset the history then I allow the native back button functionality to fire..

IE in page1.html you could have..

```
var currentPage = "index";
```

Then in your app.deviceready function include..

```
if(currentPage == "index"){
  history.go(-(history.length-9999));
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleBack, true);
}else{
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleBack,
false);
}
function handleBack(){
  // handle other logic here such as handling the back events from page2 to page1..
}
```

The real magic here is history.go(-(history.length-9999)) which basically tells the history stack to reset. Also the true statement on addEventListener allows the original registered event to fire (Native back button)..

Anyway give it a try and let me know if it works for you.

[Source](http://mclear.co.uk/2014/01/23/cordova-windows-phone-exit-application/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected IsolatedStorageSettings UserSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        }
    }
    void OnAppExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserSettings.Remove("sessionStorage");
        UserSettings.Save();
    }
    private void Page_BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_browserHistoryLength > 1)
        {
            _phoneGapView.Browser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");
            _browserHistoryLength -= 2;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //to exit app
            Application.Current.Exit += new EventHandler(OnAppExit);
           }
    }
```

Comment: An explanation wouldn't harm. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

**Navigator.app.exit()** wont work if plugin is not defined by Cordova frameowork. You might have to write your own plugin for Exit method to make it work. As a workaround, your back key hardware event can be handled in Cordova.xaml.cs and in order to exit your applicaiton you can write **

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

**It will exit your application on pressing hardware backbutton.**