# navigator.app.exitApp() is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am developing Windows phone 8 PhoneGap app. Using navigator.app.exitApp() I am quiting the app from home screen in Windows phone 7. But when I tried the same in Windows phone 8, I am getting the error `Unable to get property 'exitApp' of undefined or null reference`. I would like to know why it is undefined in Windows phone 8 and not in Window phone 7 PhoneGap app. Also, I would like to know, is there any way to quit the app programmatically in Windows phone 8 PhoneGap app?.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a simple plugin. Add file ExitApp.css to your platforms/wp8/Plugins folder with:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands
{
  class ExitApp : BaseCommand
  {
    public void execute(string options)
    {
        Application.Current.Terminate();                        
    }
  }
}
```

edit your platforms/wp8/config.xml and add to the widget tag:

```
<feature name="ExitApp">
  <param name="wp-package" value="ExitApp" />
</feature>`
```

then from you javascript call:

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "ExitApp", "execute", []);
```

You can use it in combination with backbutton event to close the app when the user clicks on backbutton in the main page:

```
function goBack(e){
  if(isInMyMainPage()) cordova.exec(null, null, "ExitApp", "execute", []);
}
document.addEventListener("backbutton", goBack, false)
```

Comment: why downvote this answer? I'm using it in production.

Comment: Thanks.It's working. One correction : in config.xml add <plugin name="ExitApp" /> to the plugins tag

Answer (score 1):

I develop small application for Windows Phone 8.1 and the code below works for me:

```
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator.app.exit()` will not exit the application it will crash the application.

In Windows Phone 8, it is handled so it will just throw an exception.

You will have to write the below code in page_BackKeyPress event in CordovaView.xaml.cs

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

It will exit your application on pressing hardware backbutton.

Comment: Navigator.app.exit() is not defined in WP8 on Cordova 3+

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here: [How to exit an application in window phone 8 with phonegap 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292714/how-to-exit-an-application-in-window-phone-8-with-phonegap-2-3/21318467#21318467) includes a fix that doesn't require any native hacking.

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.6.3, **navigator.app.exitApp()** does work.

Here is where it is called in CordovaView.cs

```
void CordovaBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    string commandStr = e.Value;

    string commandName = commandStr.Split('/').FirstOrDefault();

    if (browserDecorators.ContainsKey(commandName))
    {
        browserDecorators[commandName].HandleCommand(commandStr);
        return;
    }

    CordovaCommandCall commandCallParams = CordovaCommandCall.Parse(commandStr);

    if (commandCallParams == null)
    {
        // ERROR
        Debug.WriteLine("ScriptNotify :: " + commandStr);
    }
    else if (commandCallParams.Service == "CoreEvents")
    {
        switch (commandCallParams.Action.ToLower())
        {
            case "overridebackbutton":
                string arg0 = JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(commandCallParams.Args)[0];
                this.OverrideBackButton = (arg0 != null && arg0.Length > 0 && arg0.ToLower() == "true");
                break;
            case "__exitapp":
                Debug.WriteLine("Received exitApp command from javascript, app will now exit.");
                CordovaBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "cordova.fireDocumentEvent('pause');" });
                CordovaBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "setTimeout(function(){ cordova.fireDocumentEvent('exit'); cordova.exec(null,null,'CoreEvents','__finalexit',[]); },0);" });
                break;
            case "__finalexit":
                IsExiting = true;
                // hide the browser to prevent white flashes, since about:blank seems to always be white
                CordovaBrowser.Opacity = 0d; 
                CordovaBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank", UriKind.Absolute));
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (configHandler.IsPluginAllowed(commandCallParams.Service))
        {
            commandCallParams.Namespace = configHandler.GetNamespaceForCommand(commandCallParams.Service);
            nativeExecution.ProcessCommand(commandCallParams);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error::Plugin not allowed in config.xml. " + commandCallParams.Service);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

navigator.app.exitApp(); has been available in Apache Cordova WP8 projects since 3.4.0

```
<div onclick="navigator.app.exitApp()">Exodus</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/9v2kOwXj6sQ/O8SVpd-qjicJ

But it basically says that windows phone 8 apps shouldn't be programatically exited.

Comment: This is not correct, you can do it creating a simple pluging, look at my answerd