# Windows phonegap app certification failed due to wrong back button handling

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have developed a windows app using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap. The app works fine in windows phone. But when I submitted it in windows store, the certification failed due to the failure in app certification requirements for windows phone 5.2.4.2 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840(v=vs.105).aspx. It says that when they press the back button of the device from the home screen, the app is not closed rather it moves to the login screen.

My first screen is login screen. After logged in, the home screen is shown. If I press the back button of the device, the login page is shown again. But windows phone needs to close the app from the home rather moving to login screen.

There is no phonegap API available to close a windows application so I can't manage it in the javascript.

There is an exitApp() function available for android and it works fine. But it won't work with windows phone

I can't submit the app again and publish it until I fix the issue with back button.

Anyone faced a problem like this?

If so, Please help

Thanks

Comment: Is the login page also an HTML page? Or is it XAML?

Comment: My app is not a native app but HTML5 app which then build using phonegap. I am using jQuery Mobile for UI. So there will be only one HTML page and it is then divided into different pages

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

[navigator.app.exitApp() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950930/navigator-app-exitapp-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you finally resolved this issue. I had a similar problem which i fixed in index.js by
removing the event listener attached to the 'backbutton' event. Like this:

```
if (page == loginScreen)
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", yourMethod, false);

else
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourMethod, false);
```

`removeEventListener` will allow the default PhoneGap backbutton press to exit the app.