# phone gap - navigator.app.exitApp() is not working on windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am newbie for phonegap.I am developing a windows app. In that app, I am trying to use `navigator.app.exitApp()`. But it's not working so, I have been trying to add a custom plugin in my project. So I have downloaded the `cordova-plugin-exitapp-master.zip`.

In that zip file having follwing files

```
cordova-plugin-exitapp-master/plugin.xml
cordova-plugin-exitapp-master/www/ExitApp.js
cordova-plugin-exitapp-master/src/wp/ExitApp.cs
```

**cordova-plugin-exitapp-master/plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
       id="se.sanitarium.cordova.exitapp"
       version="1.0.0">

<name>ExitApp</name>
<description>Implements navigator.app.exitApp on WP8</description>
<license>Apache 2.0</license>
<keywords>cordova,terminate</keywords>

<js-module src="www/ExitApp.js" name="exitApp">
<merges target="navigator.app" />
</js-module>

<!-- wp8 -->
<platform name="wp8">
<config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
  <feature name="ExitApp">
    <param name="wp-package" value="ExitApp" />
  </feature>
</config-file>

<source-file src="src/wp/ExitApp.cs" />
</platform>
</plugin>
```

**cordova-plugin-exitapp-master/www/ExitApp.js**

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

module.exports = {
/**
 * Exits the PhoneGap application with no questions asked.
 */
 exitApp: function() {
 exec(null, null, 'ExitApp', 'exitApp', []);
}
};
```

**cordova-plugin-exitapp-master/src/wp/ExitApp.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;

namespace WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands
{
   public class ExitApp : BaseCommand
  {
    public void exitApp(string options)
    {
        Application.Current.Terminate();
    }
  }
}
```

So, Please any body can you tell me. In which place I have to add above plugins in my project?

Comment: Refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950930/navigator-app-exitapp-is-not-working/21027682#21027682

Comment: I already refered that url... but it has say error ... so I want to know which place I have to add in my project?

Answer (score 1):

// inside the function in which you want to exit the app write this below statements only no any plugin or anything other than this is not required to quit the app

```
    function abc[you have to write the name instead of abc]{  
   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();//you may skip this line   
      Application.Current.Terminate();                          
}
```